# Angularjs POST request status pending

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I need your help, dunno no how to solve it, I'm using MEAN stack for simple app, that has a field with input tag inside and when i fill it the data is sending to server and save in db, the problem is that post request cant reach the server.

heres is my post:

```
    $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/message',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            data: JSON.stringify({msg: $scope.message})      
        }).

        success(function(response) {
            console.log("Success " + JSON.stringify(response));
        }).

        error(function(response) {
            console.log("Error " + JSON.stringify(response));
        });
```

server side:

```
app.post('/api/message', function(req,res) {
    var message = new Message(req.body);
    message.save();

    res.status(200);
})

app.get('/api/message', function(req,res) {
    Message.find(function(err,message) {
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.json(message);
        }
    })
})
```

and this is what i get in browser dev tool

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/api/message
Request Headers
!Provisional headers are shown 
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type:application/json
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/?
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
view source
{msg: "3232"}
  msg:"3232"
```

Answer (score 0):

Following could be the issue

- actual request is not being sent from the code or browser is using cached data
- some adBlocker or some extension is blocking the request
- try removing http://localhost:3000 from the url

Comment: I i tried to show req.body in console.log(), and i saw that my msg "3232" has reached the server, but the post status is still pending, also this msg does not save into db, also im using mongoose to work with db